# Android: Getting java.lang.NullPointerException MainActivity.onCreate()

Tags: java, android

I've been searching around the web for two days now and i cant find a solution fort this problem. Im trying to create a simple login system with SQLite. Im on a 32bit Ubuntu and im using **Android SDK platform-tools 23.0.1** & **Android SDK tools 25.2.2**. The app was running fine, untill i created **RegisterFragment** Class and it crashed at **onDestroyView()**, i commented it and rebuild the project and now it is giving me the same error at **onCreate()** in **MainActivity** Class. Cant fint any specific solution for this error. The problem occurs when i change orientation and crashes at onDestroyView, if i comment it out, it crashes at onCreate, pointing to the  clickevent txtSignup.setOnClickListener.

As I wrote, the app was running fine, had no problem with changing orientations though i have layouts for both orientation, including the fragment-layout.

I have tried:
-Reinstall JDK8, Android Studio and all SDK-tools and Platform-Tools, Invalidate Caches and Restart,Searching the web for two days.

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.korp.login/com.example.korp.login.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3807)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:157)
>                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1295)
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
>                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                               at com.example.korp.login.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:92)
>                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5326)
>                                                                               at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
>                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2218)
>                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309) 
>                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3807) 
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:157) 
>                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1295) 
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317) 
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102) 
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 
>                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText txtUsername;
    EditText txtPassword;
    Button btnLogin;
    TextView txtSignup;

    Context _context;

    String username;
    String password;
    String stored;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        if(savedInstanceState!=null){
            username = savedInstanceState.getString("username");
            password = savedInstanceState.getString("password");
        }

        txtUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editUsername);
        txtPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editPassword);
        btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn);
        txtSignup = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtCreateAccount);

        txtUsername.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                txtUsername.setHint("");
                return false;
            }
        });

        txtPassword.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                txtPassword.setHint("");
                return false;
            }
        });

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                username = txtUsername.getText().toString();
                password = txtPassword.getText().toString();
                LoginDbAdapter loginDbAdapter = new LoginDbAdapter(_context);
                stored = loginDbAdapter.getSingleEntry(username);

                if(password.equals(stored)){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Användarnamn och lösenord matcher inte.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        txtSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            RegisterFragment registerFragment = new RegisterFragment();
            registerFragment.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, 0);
            registerFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");

                }
        });
    }

    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        txtUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editUsername);
        txtPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editPassword);
        CharSequence usr = savedInstanceState.getCharSequence("username");
        CharSequence psw = savedInstanceState.getCharSequence("password");
        txtUsername.setText(usr);
        txtPassword.setText(psw);
    }

    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        txtUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editUsername);
        txtPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editPassword);
        CharSequence usr = txtUsername.getText();
        CharSequence psw = txtPassword.getText();
        outState.putCharSequence("username", usr);
        outState.putCharSequence("password", psw);
    }

}
```

`RegisterFragment` class:

```
public class RegisterFragment extends DialogFragment {

    EditText regUserName;
    EditText regEmail;
    EditText regPass;
    EditText regPassTwo;
    Button register;
    Button cancel;

    LoginDbAdapter loginDbAdapter;

    String userName;
    String email;
    String password;
    String passwordTwo;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.register_fragment, container, false);

        if(savedInstanceState!=null){
            userName = savedInstanceState.getString("username");
            email = savedInstanceState.getString("email");
            password = savedInstanceState.getString("password");
            passwordTwo = savedInstanceState.getString("password2");
        }


        regUserName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.reg_username);
        regEmail = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.reg_email);
        regPass = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.reg_pass);
        regPassTwo = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.reg_pass_two);
        register = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnRegistera);
        cancel = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);

        register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                userName = regUserName.getText().toString();
                email = regEmail.getText().toString();
                password = regPass.getText().toString();
                passwordTwo = regPassTwo.getText().toString();

                if(userName.equals("")|| email.equals("")||
                   password.equals("")|| passwordTwo.equals("")){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Var god fyll i alla fält.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //return;
                }
                if (!password.equals(passwordTwo)){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Lösenorden matchar inte.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //return;
                }
                if(!email.contains("@")){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Ogiltig email.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //return;
                }
                else{
                    loginDbAdapter.insertEntry(userName, password, email);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Registreringen lyckades", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });

        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            getActivity().getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            loginDbAdapter.close();

            }
        });



        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroyView(){
        super.onDestroyView();
        loginDbAdapter.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        CharSequence usr = regUserName.getText().toString();
        CharSequence mail = regEmail.getText().toString();
        CharSequence pass = regPass.getText().toString();
        CharSequence passT = regPassTwo.getText().toString();

        savedInstanceState.putCharSequence("username", usr);
        savedInstanceState.putCharSequence("email", mail);
        savedInstanceState.putCharSequence("password", pass);
        savedInstanceState.putCharSequence("password2", passT);
    }    
}
```

Comment: CharSequence usr = txtUsername.getText(); is where the null pointer is. I would assume that the EditText you're getting the text from is null.

Comment: The exception i think is in line 92 in MainActivity the txtSignup.setOnClickListener(), but the app crashes only when i change the orientation and unfortunatly RegisterFragment dont save the states..removing .toString() dont solve the problem either. In portrait-mode everything works fine, i can get the fragment and i can back from it without a problem. Its when i change the orientation, with or without the fragment.

Comment: If i comment out txtSignup.setOnClickListener() i can change orientation without problem and the states are saved as it should. I think i do wrong with the fragments lifecycle.

Comment: have you attached configchanges to the activity in your manifest xml?

Comment: No..what do you suggest? Can you give me an example?

Comment: <Activity android:name=".MainActivity" configChanges="orientation"/> in your manifest file

Comment: Yes i have added <Activity android:name=".MainActivity" configChanges="screenSize|keyboardHidden"/>, the RegisterFragment on the other hand can not be added to the AndroidManifest. As i wrote yesterday it worked before, then something happend...

Comment: I would assume there is a mistake somewhere in your XMLs, or something. The issue here is that the `findViewById()` method is not finding that view on the inflated layout and thus it is null.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Solution:** registerFragment is going to be null because it has not been added (yet) The if-statement solved it, but since FragmentTransition was not added until API level 19 and i am debugging in API level 17, the Logcat is giving me this error first time a tap txtSignup:

**Could not find class 'android.transition.Transition'.**

But for some reason it works.

```
txtSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                RegisterFragment registerFragment = new RegisterFragment();
                if(registerFragment !=null) {
                registerFragment.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, 0);
                registerFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");

                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: Please consider not disregarding errors the IDE is throwing. It is not plotting against you. It is telling you there is a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Dont know, it crashed before. Now it dont.